# Minimum distance between two rectangles with known size and orientation

Tags: geometry, optimization, rectangles

I have faced a problem, that I need to calculate a shortest distance between two rectangles, which are on a different angles.

[image: Rectangulars]

> **Known parameters**: length, width, angle and coordinate of center point of each
> rectangular.

Comment: Do you know the orientations (angles) of the two rectangles?

Comment: Yes, angles I know too.

Comment: which distance? the shortest?

Comment: Yes. The shortest distance.

Answer (score 2):

The typical method is to rotate the coordinate system to one box and check the vertices of the other. This transforms the problem to this:

[image: pic]

<sub>NOTE: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection and links theirin. In separating axis theorem there is a way to find minimum distance which is equivalent to the above.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deduce that the shortest distance will be attained for the *vertices* of one of the rectangles (but possibly the sides of the other). Then you really have to compare the distances of $8$ given points from $8$ given lines, which shouldn't be that bad...

Comment: can you explain more detailed? I don't understood. :) You saying to find 8 points of each rectangulars and compare distance between each point?

Comment: Getting the minimum distance between a point and a line is easy. Getting the minimum distance between a point and _a line segment_ is much harder to do right. You have to account for the ends and see if the minimum point falls outside the segment, and on which side.